# Objective C - Problem with NSMutableArray and NSTableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a class named Person and in this class is the property PersonName (amongst others).

A MutableArray `MyUserInfoArr` contains many Person objects.

I want to list each PersonName in a Cell of a TableView? How do I do this? 
Thanks in advance.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    Person *myPerson;    
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
       cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    NSString *cellValue = [myUserInfoArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.text = cellValue;
```

---

```
if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        Person *myPerson = [myUserInfoArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = myPerson.DisplayName;
        NSLog(@"abc %i",indexPath.section);
}
```

This is my code, it ran, but it just return the attribute Person.DisplayName of the last object Person in the myUserInfoArr. How to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Person *person = [myUserInfoArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = person.PersonName;
```

The reason your code doesn't work: the `text` property needs to be an `NSString *`, not a `Person *`.

Comment: But [myUserInfoArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] in logic not return a NSString because myUserInfoArr contains many objects of Person Class.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to just set the text with:

```
Person *person = [MyUserInfoArr objectAtIndex:[indexPath indexAtPosition:1]];
cell.textLabel.text = person.PersonName;
```

indexPath contains two indexes, first is the section index, the 2nd is the item's index within the section. So I'm assuming in your case you have a single section, that's why there is nothing to do with the indexAtPosition:0.

You also have to set up the table's data source methods, these tell your table view how many sections/rows it should show:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [MyUserInfoArr count];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it displayed the numbers of rows in my TableView but in the line:

cell.textLabel.text = [MyUserInfoArr objectAtIndex:[indexPath indexAtPosition:1]].PersonName

There's an error : Request more member 'PersonName' in something not a structure or union. What does it mean then?

Comment: @ThyPhuong: The error probably meant that the thing returned was not a Person*. I think the problem was that the chained syntax was not supported. I've edited my above answer, try now.